# SQL Using the Exists function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables need to join. Here's the original query:

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT(ca.cust_acct_id)                 
FROM
   cwo_work_order_acct ca              
INNER JOIN
   cat_cust_item_acct_activity acty                
      ON                      ca.organization_id = acty.organization_id                     
      AND ca.cust_acct_id = acty.cust_acct_id                     
      AND ca.cust_acct_code = acty.cust_acct_code              
INNER JOIN
   cwo_work_order_line_item cli                         
      ON                          acty.organization_id = cli.organization_id                         
      AND acty.wkstn_id = cli.wkstn_id                         
      AND acty.trans_seq = cli.trans_seq                         
      AND acty.business_date = cli.business_date                         
      AND acty.rtl_loc_id = cli.rtl_loc_id                         
      AND acty.rtrans_lineitm_seq = cli.rtrans_lineitm_seq              
      AND cli.price_status_enum ='ESTIMATE'
```

Each row in `cwo_work_order_line_item` represents a item on a certain work order grouped together by transaction sequences. This query is joining this and another table for a report, `cat_cust_item_acct_activity`. That table shows different transactions dealing with a certain account.

This certain section of the report is supposed to only show items that are charged as 'Estimate.' This query works perfectly fine until an item gets changed to an actual price on a different transaction than when it was set up.

The problem is that the table `cwo_work_order_line_item` gets a new item inserted into it with a different transaction sequence (trans_seq column) and `cat_cust_item_acct_activity` gets a new item as well. This happens instead of actually modifying the original row representing the item ean each table.

What this means is that the report is still showing the original item (the setup item) on the report even after the price was changed from Estimate to Actual.

Hopefully you guys can help. I think I might have to do a EXISTS check, but the problem is that new row inserted in `cat_cust_item_acct_activity` has nothing relating that to its original "set up" item

Comment: There must be some relation between them, like an itemid or productid or something? Without a relation, you cannot find related rows, whether you use `EXISTS` or a join.

Comment: So the problem is that once an item goes from "ESTIMATE" to "ACTUAL", this section of the report should no longer display anything, but instead it still displays the ESTIMATE records? If so, couldn't you just INNER JOIN on the same CLI table (join it twice, once searching for status = ESTIMATE as [cli1] and once as [cli2] with status <> "ACTUAL"

Comment: OK so I just figured out that there is a row from each table that corresponds to each other. So now i just need the syntax, which i might need some help with.

    If the row acty.item_acct_activity_code ==  'MODIFY_PRICE'

Then find the corresponding item in table cli. 
cli.rtrans_lineitm_seq corresponds to acty.cust_item_acct_detail_item_nbr

Once we get that, we want to make sure that doesnt get added